# How to download a web page content including an SVG element as a pdf file?

Tags: php, html, drupal, svg, d3.js

I have rendered a page that includes an SVG element which creates a pie chart.

The SVG element works fine when rendering it in a web page. But when I save the same webpage file as a PDF, the SVG element (which is a pie chart) is not rendered in the PDF file. The SVG element is added by the d3.js library.

Here is the relevant code of my webpage file that I am using for adding the SVG element.

```
var svg = d3.select(".testchart").append("svg")
.attr("class", "pie-chart")
.attr("width", width)
.attr("height", height)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")
rotate(" + rotate + ")");
```

The above code is not the full html code, it is just the line of code for adding the SVG element on a webpage.

Comment: Let me ask the obvious: How exactly do you download that HTML file, which contains an image generated by Javascript? You need a 'downloader' that will execute the Javascript and draw your SVG before it stores it as a PDF. Can it do that?

Comment: You can try phantomjs in your case. See the [tutorial](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

Comment: http://www.cloudformatter.com/CSS2Pdf.SVGCharts.d3Charts shows the exact sample

Comment: Thanks Kevin, This is exactly what is my requirement. I have done with this and working fine. Thank you so much for your time.